# Empty screen when debugging

Tags: xamarin.ios

When attempting to debug (Run -> Debug), the "waiting for debugger" dialog appears, and subsequently disappears.  The simulator starts up to the home screen, I click on my app, and all that happens is a black screen appears.  No breakpoints are hit, and the application never appears to do anything.  Simply running the application without debugging works as expected.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't fixed this already - the same thing happened to me. And as Driss says in the comments having a folder called `Resources` in your project gives the iPhone Simulator a heartattack and crashes it from the looks of things, without even copying your app bundle to the simulator directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a very similar issue. Did this happen with your project "all of a sudden?", did you rename your View's .xib file? did you have a NavigationController then delete it and now have this issue?

Can you also please post your "FinishedLaunching" code from your Main.cs please.

Driss.

Comment: I haven't been able to debug at any point - although I hadn't tried until recently.  I can create a completely new solution, start debug - it "waits to connect", then the app loads to a black screen and immediately quits (without visible exception or output).

Comment: Hmm, you wouldn't happen to have created a folder called Resources did you?